# Is there a way for MySQL to wait for rows matching a condition to be inserted

Tags: mysql, blocking, wait, polling, long-polling

Let's say i was writing an aplication where'd i'd need to get notifications in real time from a server, and let's say those notifications are stored on a mysql database. 
For me to get them i'd have to keep polling the mysql server (keep repeating the same select
query till i actually get results) but i figure that is very unefficient way of doing it since most of the time the select would turn up empty . If i do it often it's unreasonable strain on the server if i do it rarely the notifications would come in very late.
So i was wondering if there is a way for say a mysql query to block until a result matching a condition becomes available.

```
list = query ("SELECT * FROM `notifications` WHERE `unread`=1") ;
```

instead of returning an empty list if there is no unread notifications , it would instead wait till there actually are unread notifications to return

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend using the [producer consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) pattern, implemented with a new table as the "work queue". There is no need for a stored procedure, because the trigger is so simple.

1. A trigger would populate the work queue
2. Code would poll the work queue table. Because the table would be very small, the query would be fast and low-load.
3. Code would do whatever you need and delete rows from the table when finished - keeping it as small as possible

Create a table with the id of the `notification` to be processed and a "processing status" column, for example:

```
create table work_queue (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    notification_id int references notifications,
    status enum ('ready', 'processing', 'failed')
);
```

Create a simple trigger that populates a the work queue table:

```
delimiter $
create trigger producer after insert on notifications
for each row begin 
    insert into work_queue (notification_id, status) 
    select new.id, 'ready'
    where new.unread;
end; $
delimiter ;
```

Your code would have the pseudo code:

1. `select * from work_queue where status = 'ready' order by id limit 1`
2. `update work_queue set status = 'processing' where id = <row.id>`
3. Do what you need to `notifications where id = <row.notification_id>`
4. either `delete from work_queue where id = <row.id>` or `update work_queue set status = 'failed' where id = <row.id>` (you'll have to figure out what to do with failed items)
5. Sleep 1 second (this pause needs to be about the same as the peak arrival rate of notifications - you'll need to tune this to balance between work_queue size and server load)
6. goto 1.

If you have a single process polling, there is no need for locking worries. If you have multiple processes polling, you'll need to handle race conditions.

Comment: interesting idea , i take it there is no other way besides polling,
thanks for the ancwer :)

Comment: there's no other way, so you want to make your polling as fast as possible. I have to say, that is the toughest 10 points of reputation I've ever earned :)

Comment: If you want to reduce DB load from all these pollings, you might make the producer to lock the work_queue table for reads and unlock it only when there is some work available.